# Comparable dynamics of linear 2-dim $x'(t)=F(x(t))$ and $x'(t)=t^{-2}F(x(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Any advice or reference that compares dynamics of 2-dimensional linear system $x'(t)=F(x(t))$ with $y'(t)=\frac{F(y(t))}{t^2}$ would be much appreciated. $F$ is $C^1$ function in its domain.

Comment: $$y(t)=x\left(c-\frac1t\right)$$

Comment: can I find an example of application of such systems?

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Thanks so much and I was wondering if there is an application where dynamical systems of type $t^{-2}F(y(t))$ are studied

Comment: The fact that the factor $t^{-2}$ is not autonomous makes this unlikely, one rather finds changes of times $x'(t)=g(x(t))F(x(t))$ with $g$ scalar.

Answer (score 1):

The direction fields are the same, only the lengths of the vectors differ. Thus the trajectories are the same as curves and thus are reparametrizations of each other. Thus
$$
y(s)=x(\phi(s))\implies y'(s)=x'(ϕ(s))·ϕ'(s)
$$
and comparing the vector fields, $ϕ'(s)=\dfrac1{s^2}$ or $t=\phi(s)=\dfrac1{s_0}-\dfrac1s$ resp. $s=\dfrac{s_0}{1-s_0t}$.

Comment: Is there a basic text that allows to look into this in systematic way?